# Hide keyboard Microphone in W10 Mobile (UWP) (Xamarin forms)

Tags: uwp, keyboard, xamarin.forms, hide, microphone

I'm developing an application for W10 Mobile (UWP) in Xamarin forms, the case is that I am using the telephone keypad when a specific entry has the focus, the problem is that at the top of the keyboard appears the Voice detection command I am not interested in having it, after searching in the official documentation and other forums have not found anything about this topic , if anyone knows how to hide this command  would be useful. Thank you.

**My entry:**

```
var entry = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Telephone };
```

**Image command voice:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JbwL.png]

**Documentation Choose a keyboard for an Entry:** https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is that at the top of the keyboard appears the Voice detection command I am not interested in having it, after searching in the official documentation and other forums have not found anything about this topic , if anyone knows how to hide this command would be useful. Thank you.

The keyboard is system level. Currently there is no such api to hide the dictation button with programming. However, you could hide it in the keyboard setting. You could refer to the following screenshot:

**Settings -> Time&language -> Keyboard ->More keyboard settings -> Show the dictation button.**
[image]